# Escaping URL Helper in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I need to send a text email with a link for the user to click. It's a user verification email. The issue I am having is that the URL helper keeps escaping the characters. I feel I have tried the below in every possible combination but to no avail.

```
echo $this->Url->build([
    "controller" => "Users",
    "action" => "verify", 
    "?" => ['email' => $email, 'hash' => $hash]  
    ],[
    "escape" => false,
    "fullBase" => true
    ]);
```

This results in http://www.mydomain.co.uk/users/verify?email=chris%40domain.co.uk&hash=b56a4eea3b495db226888f2f89e7678f where the '@' and '&' charachters are beeing escaped.

Another issue with this is that cake can't access the hash variable but it can the email, ie.

```
echo $this->request->query('hash') //doesn't print anything
echo $this->request->query('email') //prints email with the @ symbol
```

Comment: Specifically what version of Cake are you using? The documentation indicates that passing an array as the second argument was only added in 3.3.5.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I'm using 3.2.13. Does this mean prior to 3.3.5 you can't escape special characters in the build function? If so do you know another way to get about doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Greg Schmidt for pointing out the version inconsistency.

FYI; You can only use the escaping for CakePHP version 3.3.5 and above (As of Nov '16).

I used htmlspecialchars_decode($this->Url->build()) to solve the problem